# Promise (then - catch) or Async / Await (with Try-Catch) for exceptions control

Tags: node.js, async-await, try-catch

I want to know how to work within async / await, if it is more convenient to try-catch inside async/await, or just work with promises with then-catch only without using async-await

I have this little code in Node JS and Express as an example to better understand:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports = {

    //HTTP POST Method

    createPost: async(req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                errors: errors.array()[0].msg
            });
        }

        try {
            const { title, content, imageUrl } = req.body;

            const newPost = new Post({
                title,
                content,
                imageUrl
            });

            const post = await newPost.save();

            if (!post) {
                return res.status(422).json({
                    errors: 'Error'
                });
            }

            return res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Post created successfully!',
                post: {
                    title: title,
                    content: content,
                    image: imageUrl,
                }
            });

        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                errors: 'Error'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thank for your time!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  `try/catch` will catch either synchronously thrown exceptions or rejected promises on an `await`.  Can you make your question a bit more specific?  Which lines of code are you asking about?

Comment: FYI, your `if (!post) ...` statement is likely never going to be triggered.  If the `.save()` fails, it will probably reject, not resolve with `null`.  The reject from the `await` will go to your `catch()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to know how to work within async / await, if it is more convenient to try-catch inside async / await, or just work with promises without using async-await, only promises with then and catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't ask a very specific question, I'll give you some comments and alternatives on your code.  But first a few points:

Programming with `async` and `await` is optional.  When to use it is partly opinion and partly depends upon exactly what you're doing.  If you have only a single asynchronous operation that's part of your code flow, then there's generally no particular the reasons to use `await` are less compelling as a simple `.then()` and `.catch()` will be similar in complexity to the `try/catch`.

If you have any danger of synchronously thrown exceptions that you need to catch, then you have to use `try/catch` anyway (regardless of your asynchronous design).

---

Now here are a few notes about your code:

In this block of code:

```
       const post = await newPost.save();

        if (!post) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                errors: 'Error'
            });
        }
```

If the `newPost.save()` operations fails, then it will reject the promise.  If it rejects the promise, then, because you're using `await`, that rejection will go to your `catch()` handler, so it will never get to the `if (!post) ...` block at all.  I'd be surprised if that check was ever useful.

Since you only have one asynchronous operation in your control flow and I don't see any danger of synchronously thrown exceptions, I would probably just use `.then()` and `.catch()` like this:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports = {

    //HTTP POST Method

    createPost: (req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                errors: errors.array()[0].msg
            });
        }

        const { title, content, imageUrl } = req.body;

        const newPost = new Post({
            title,
            content,
            imageUrl
        });

        newPost.save().then(post => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Post created successfully!',
                post: {
                    title: title,
                    content: content,
                    image: imageUrl,
                }
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                errors: 'Error'
            });
        });
    }
}
```

> I want to know how to work within async / await, if it is more convenient to try-catch inside async / await, or just work with promises without using async-await, only promises with then and catch.

There are no uniform guidelines.  If I have a single asynchronous operation in my control flow, I use `.then()` and `.catch()`.  If I have multiple asynchronous operations and they need to be serialized (one after the other), then I use `async/await`.  That's just my personal style and what I find the cleanest and most convenient.  There are a few other cases where `async` functions are useful as just a default `catch` handler so that any synchronously thrown exception is automatically converted to a rejection for the caller and there are a few cases where you have a mix of synchronous and asynchronous flow inside the function and sometimes the execution may be entirely synchronous.  Wrapping that inside an `async` function automatically makes sure that the interface always returns a promise, even if the execution was entirely synchronous for some set of conditions.

This comes up regularly in caching.  If the value is in the cache, it's entirely synchronous to retrieve it, but your interface needs to return a promise no matter what.  An `async` function will do that for you automatically.  One can code this manually by  doing a `return Promise.resolve(cachedValue)`, but sometimes an `async` function is just cleaner for this type of case.

Comment: thank very much, all is most clear. I understand much better, the question I have now is, what happens if I have a helpers file (crypt.js) with an async method (called encrypt) with two wait (one await for bcrypt salt and one await for bcrypt password hash) inside, and that method is called by a controller (userController.js), the controller method (called postRegister) that calls the helper async method, postRegister method should it also be async?

Comment: @FelipePoncedeLeón - As I said multiple times in my answer.  If I have multiple asynchronous operations in the function that need to be sequenced, I tend to use `async/await` and `try/catch` as the code looks simpler than chaining multiple `.then()` together.  There are still cases where I might use `.catch()` with `await` when I need to handle an individual error separately rather than one error handler for any rejected promise. Or, you can use multiple try/catch for that too.  Functions you call have their own reasons to be `async` or not that isn't affected by being called by an `async` fn.

Comment: Now everything is clear, thank you very much for your time and patience!